# How to split SQL query results into chunks in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I am trying to break query results into chunks using PHP but can't seem to figure out how to formulate either a query or a loop to break the results into batches of four and surround those four rows with specific HTML elements.

The content is specifically a photography portfolio, where I am just attempting to display photos row by row, but the way I need to style it calls for each row to basically be a separate set of information.

This is the code I'm working with thus far:

```
<ul class="no-bullet">
<?php

require("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM dv_photo_work LIMIT 4";

$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  print('
     <li><img alt="'.$row["img_title"].'" src="'.$row["img_slug"].'></li>');
}


?>
</ul>
```

I only want four images to be in that list though.  And then another four in another list.  **Can you help me reformulate the loop to make it return four records and then begin a new query of the following four records in another list?**  There will be approximately 100 records in the database that I will be retrieving this from, so it would have to be able to continue until the entire table is listed.

I imagine this is similar to a pagination process, yet that is another technique that I am unfamiliar with.  I'm assuming it's a simple adjustment to the query and mark-up, however I could understand it being something that requires a bit more code creativity than a simple fix.

Many thanks,

Joshie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul class="no-bullet">
<?php
require("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM dv_photo_work";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
$i =1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   print('<li><img alt="'.$row["img_title"].'" src="'.$row["img_slug"].'></li>');
   if ($i%4 == 0) echo "</ul><ul class='no-bullet'>";
   $i++;
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I see how there should be an empty ul-element at the end but when I ran this just now they were grouped how should be and there was no remainder list left unpopulated.  @Orangepill Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First! move that logic far away from the html, that will allow you to see the problem more clearly. Second! what about two classes a Class A that represents an n-length list of query results. Class A should be an iterator, so that a Class B can pull arbitrary length chunks of results and return    appropriately sized result objects. maybe there's a third class whose instances represent the sized constrained result. So all in all three classes A representing a full list of results, B acting on a and returning instances of C which would represent your sized constrained result chunks.

This was originally a comment, but it was too long, so I had to make it an answer (sorry if it's too 'teach a man to fish' I just don't want to write php...)

Comment: How would I get the query results in the mock-up if I don't directly insert it where it should be placed?  And while I am following you on the strategy of how to compose the logic I am looking for, I am a with these languages and I am looking for more direct recommendations on which PHP functions or SQL commands to employ in a scenario like this and how to situate them within the mark-up.

Comment: dude fair enough. As far as the insertion goes that C class I mentioned, it's instances provided the object had a method that when called returned it's contents  wrapped in html would be a great way to keep the realms separate and still have simplicity so far as having just a php object mixed with the html, 'cept this object is (would be) a little more innocent as far as side effects go...

Answer (score 0):

Get all your results, read them into a multidimensional array, and then split them into groups with array_chunk().

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dv_photo_work",$link);
$results = array();
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $results[] = $line;
}
$lists = array_chunk($results,4);
foreach ($lists as $list) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($list as $result) {
        echo '<li><img alt="'.$result["img_title"].'" src="'.$result["img_slug"].'></li>'
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I went through the logic and this makes sense, but it's giving me an internal server error when I run it, and that usually means there's some sort of syntax issue going on.  @Otome do you see anything that might cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of the logic involved, using the modulus operator (%) to change the HTML at every fourth record:

```
$i = 0;

// within your current while-loop:
    if ($i % 4 == 0) {
        // $i is a multiple of 4 (including 0, the first record)
        if ($i > 0) {
            // finish the previous ul-tag
        }
        // start a new block of HTML (the ul)
    }
    // output the li
    $i += 1;

// after the loop, close the last ul
```

Comment: I did this but for some reason the `<ul>` is being closed and opened after each line, not only the fourth.

Comment: @Joshie My mistake, it should have been `$i % 4 == 0`. I've corrected my outline.